# Walletnotify not working

Tags: bitcoind, wallet-notify

Here's my bitcoin.conf:

```
server=1
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcuser=userrunningbitcoind
rpcpassword=passwordofuserrunningbitcoind
rpcport=7788
walletnotify=/home/userrunningbitcoind/transaction.sh %s
```

And here's my transaction.sh, which I've tried running manually already. This works without issue on its own:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -d "txid=$1" http://127.0.0.1/api/process-payment
```

What else can I try to get walletnotify going?

EDIT:

I've additionally found this in my debug.log:

```
2018-01-19 05:49:22 Binding RPC on address 0.0.0.0 port 7788 failed.
2018-01-19 05:49:22 No rpcpassword set - using random cookie authentication
2018-01-19 05:49:22 Generated RPC authentication cookie /home/userrunningbitcoind/.bitcoin/.cookie
```

Comment: It should be working, note that it will only trigger for transaction to addresses in your wallet. Have you made a transaction ?  To debug what is happening, you can see .bitcoin/debug.log

Comment: @darkknight I've made transactions to attempt to test it. The debug log is enormous, and seems to be filled with unrelated messages. How would I filter it appropriately?

Comment: Search for transaction.sh in the log ...it should show up

Comment: grep -i "transaction.sh" debug.log returned no lines. Is it possible that my bitcoin.conf is being ignored?

Comment: @Fibericon have you tried connecting to the RPC to see if the other settings have taken effect?

Comment: How would I test this?

Comment: @MeshCollider It's apparently not binding RPC. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yeah if it is failing to bind the port its more likely a server issue, try a different port maybe

Comment: @MeshCollider I tried a few different ports, but no dice.

Comment: What about the default port? Maybe it's a permission issue

Comment: @MeshCollider Looks like it defaults to 8332 (when I remove the port line in bitcoin.conf), but it still gives the same error in debug.log

Comment: Have you tried curling it? `walletnotify=curl /home/userrunningbitcoind/transaction.sh %s`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to restart bitcoind again after you make any change in bitcoin.conf file. It seems as if you set an rpcpassword in the conf but didnt restart the bitcoind service. You have everything set up properly i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
2018-01-19 05:49:22 Binding RPC on address 0.0.0.0 port 7788 failed.
```

if you are using rpcallowip, you need to also use rpcbind. By default, the recent BTC versions are limited to 127.0.0.1 so there's no need to use rpcallowip or rpcbind if your BitcoinD and your app are running on same server.

So either you remove rpcallowip from config, or add rpcbind=0.0.0.0 and then restart bitcoind. Also, everytime you restart bitcoind, you need to load the wallet, as default loading of wallet is removed.  So if wallet is not loaded, walletnotify will not work.